# Is there a Minecraft console command for randomly generating specific items in the world?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am setting up a Minecraft server for players to explore. I'd like to use the console to generate items, such as eggs and boxes, throughout the world without me having to manually place each one.

Can this be accomplished via a console command? Something like: `/summon [entity_name]` but with a randomly determined location?

Comment: Probably, but that's an entire project. We're here to when you encounter issues with things you try yourself, not for doing projects for you. Also, do you mean item entities? Having lots of those everywhere first causes lag and then they despawn after 5 minutes.

Comment: Weird, the system calls you a "new contributor", despite 177 points. Do you still care about 7 years old question? It seems fine to me, I could vote to undelete.

Comment: Oh, haha, I forgot about that closed/deleted question. Sure, I just voted to undelete it. I never did learn why it was considered off topic. Sometimes SE sites feel too aggressively moderated IMO.

Comment: For clarity, I wasn't asking anyone to do a project for me. I've searched a lot and cannot find a way to place items (say a treasure box) in the world as if I ran around doing that manually. I don't have much experience with Minecraft, so I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: So your actual issue is "how do I place a chest prefilled with items in MCBE", that is the detail that you're stuck on?

Comment: No, I actually wanted to know how to randomly place any item via the console. Is my question really not focused enough when the answer would be something like: "Just type: `/generate [item_id] random`" or "It's not possible without a plugin"? I'll edit the question.

Comment: Question edited to be as specific as possible. Please consider reopening it. Thank you.

Comment: It is very likely possible, but it needs a random number generator, a random item and placement chooser, you need to actually get the item into the chest (which is very difficult in MCBE because of the missing NBT in commands), etc.

Comment: @FabianRöling this could likely be done with /spreadplayers and /execute

Answer (score 0):

You could try making chests with different sets and clone them randomly to random locations